# How to use a custom dotnet library method in SSRS of SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: dll, reference, ssrs-2008

I need to use a custom dll within my SSRS report. Please guide me how to do this in SQL Server 2008 R2 business intelligence studio.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about your problem.  What are you trying to achieve with the dll?  How far have you got with creating a report?

Comment: @Daryl Wenman-Bateson, I'm exposing a textbox in ssrs and need to restrict special characters from entering in to it. I have a library to do that and need to call it from SSRS. If you have an alternate solution to do this please guide me..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the question is quite old, but as I had the same issue recently and as your question is not yet answered, i will give you a link that explains what to do

[How to use custom assemblies or embedded code in Reporting Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920769/en-us)

From you mail I suspect that you didn't deploy the dll on the server bin directory (and modifiy the config file).

Hope this will help you or someone else :-)

Answer (score 0):

To reference a DLL, select the yellow background surrounding the report (in design view) and select Report Properties (not Report Data).  Within here you have a Code section, for writing custom code and a References section to reference custom DLL's.

That said, if you want this functionality to be used by many reports, consider wrapping the SSRS reports within a c# web app.  This will enable you to make use of common repeating code (like parameter passing) and reduce ongoing maintenance by code reuse.

Comment: I tried using the References section before i post the question and got an error- Cannot load the assembly or one of its dependencies. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Can you add it to a standard .net project and utilise?  If not, maybe you need to rebuild it.  If you can, possibly a location or permission issue.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153561.aspx